# PDF "Expected a Dict Object" on Adobe Reader But Perfect on Chrome

Tags: pdf

With the following pdf file I created by js.
http://www.dnpi.com.hk/errorfile.pdf
I am able to open with Chrome/Mobile perfectly.
But got Error message "Expected a Dict Object" on Adobe Acrobat DC.
Following with the image of the file openned with Chrome.
Anyone got any idea how this happens?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AN7V.png)

Comment: "The requested URL /errorfile.pdf was not found on this server."

Comment: Sorry that was a server without SSL. I have corrected the link.

Comment: For the SSL. Sorry that since my previous link was https, while you have the error cretificate of example.com, browsers will automatically add https://www.example.com for your http://www.example.com. Need to delete the certificate of www.example.com before you can go back to "http". Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This PDF file produces errors in xpdf:

```
$ xpdf ~/git/david-cv/errorfile.pdf 
Syntax Error (174): Dictionary key must be a name object
Syntax Error (176): Dictionary key must be a name object
Syntax Error (180): Dictionary key must be a name object
Syntax Error (182): Dictionary key must be a name object
Syntax Error (191): Dictionary key must be a name object
Syntax Error: Kid object (page 1) is wrong type (stream)
```

It seems to be objecting to the `page 1` object.

Opening, this PDF in a text editor, there is a problem with the page 1 object:

```
3 0 obj
<</Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
/Resources 2 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 595.28 841.89]
/Contents 4 0 R
endobj
```

It's missing a closing `>>` for the Page dictionary object.

The PDF file is incorrect, although Chrome/Mobile seems to be able to recover it.